# Issue with circular import in Django tutorials?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I am getting a circular import error with a basic Django page setup and I have no idea why. Am following the guides of at least 4 or 5 different tutorials with the same result.

I have varied the syntax in the webapps urls.py to no avail. Any ideas ?

- mainproject

**urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

- webapp

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

- Error

  "/Users/Desktop/website/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 706, in url_patterns
  raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'members.urls' from '/Users/Desktop/website/main/members/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: can you share your INSTALLED_APPS part of settings.py?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'members.apps.MembersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]